# What does the ordering/index of cluster_centers_ represent in KMeans clustering SKlearn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have implemented the following code

```
k_mean = KMeans(n_clusters=5,init=centroids,n_init=1,random_state=SEED).fit(X_input)
k_mean.cluster_centers_.shape
>>
(5, 50)
```

I have 5 clusters of the data.

**How are the clusters ordered? Are the indices of the clusters centres representing the `labels`**?

Means does the `cluster_center` index at `0th` position represent the label = 0 or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) you have a smiliar example:

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
>>> kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
>>> kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
>>> kmeans.predict([[0, 0], [12, 3]])
array([1, 0], dtype=int32)
>>> kmeans.cluster_centers_
array([[10.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

The indexes are ordered yes. Btw with `k_mean.cluster_centers_.shape`you only return the shape of your array, and not the values. So in your case you have 5 clusters, and the dimension of your features is 50.

To get the nearest point, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234336/value-at-kmeans-cluster-centers-in-sklearn-kmeans).

Comment: Thank you. I know about shape but it would not have been a good thing to plot all the 5,50 D here that is why I used shape